# How to run Apache Ignite sql queries over a rest-api

Tags: rest, http, filter, ignite

I am trying to access Apache Ignite over the http-rest api . I see that the api mostly provides ability to request data with a specific key ( meaning you should always know/have the key to query data) .

However i would like to understand

1) if we have the ability to say query a set of records which are filtered based on one or more of the value fields of the POJO value.

2) If we can run join like sql-queries through the rest api when my data is as part of more then 1 cache and some fields in them have common values to create the relation among caches.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [REST API documentation](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/rest-api) for the list of the available commands - there are commands that allow to execute SQL.

Also take a look at the [Ignite SQL documentation](https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/select) for the syntax reference and some examples.

Finally, please see the Ignite SQL examples - you can find them in the Ignite distribution or in the git repository. E.g. [SqlDmlExample](https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/examples/sql/SqlDmlExample.java) should give a notion of how to execute various SQL queries on an Ignite cache.